# What's the difference between Sunspot keywords and fulltext

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, sunspot

I am refactoring my code and found out that I use both `keywords` and `fulltext` to search. The use of `fulltext` is used at [Readme](https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot#readme) and `keywords` is used in [Wiki](https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot/wiki/Fulltext-search). There was a [discussion](http://groups.google.com/group/ruby-sunspot/browse_thread/thread/815cd71bfb81be59/feaec2d3dd6f7bcf?lnk=gst&q=keywords#feaec2d3dd6f7bcf) mentioning that those are different ways of doing the same thing, however it does not explain what the differences are. Plus I can't find `keywords` in the [API doc](http://sunspot.github.com/docs/index.html#).

So can those two be used inter-changeably? What are the differences between them? What are the limitations of each? Anything to watch out for?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There is no difference between them, keywords is an alias for fulltext

```
alias_method :keywords, :fulltext
```

The line above is defined in [`sunspot/lib/sunspot/dsl/standard_query.rb`](https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot/blob/master/sunspot/lib/sunspot/dsl/standard_query.rb#L106).